# How do I query two related models in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm stuck on a Laravel blog project I'm working on. I have 2 related models, User and Post, and then in my blade file a search form which will query both  models for result. In my Controller method, I have:

```
    $q = $request->keyword;
    $results = Post::where ('title', 'LIKE', '%{$q}%')->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%{$q}%')->with(['user' => function($x){
        $x->orWhere('name',  'LIKE', '%{$q}%')->get();
    }])->get();
return view('result')->withResults($results);
```

Issue is I don't get a response in my blade file. I suspect there's a bug in my controller method but I just can't wrap my head around it. I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: `$q` isn't available in your `function($x)` unless you have `function($x) use($q){ ... });` Do you have error reporting turned on? Also, `->with()` doesn't exactly query the relationships to limit what's returned via the `Post::` query, that's done via `->whereHas(...)`

Comment: @Tim thanks.I also did use($q) but still didn't get a response.

Comment: Hmm... Check your logs; if there's an error, you'll find it there. `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Or turn on errors via `.env`, by setting `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: Thanks @Tim.There seems to be no error as the Network tab on the console is showing that the request status code is OK (200).However, I still get a blank page when I query an item from the other model (User) but get a response when the query finds the item been searched for in the parent model (Post), meaning the query for the second model failed.Hoping I made the issue clear?